# Dax measure to avoid all slicers except one in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Here, I have a dataset in which there is an eventid (ID) captured for each event generating in each department(DEPT), with its timestamp(event-time).
Each event captured is categorized as OPEN/ CLOSE(event status).
I want to show the efficiency of each department, which is defined as-
Total cases closed Divided by Total no. of cases registered in that Department.

I tried using 100% stacked bar chart, but the result in it changes every time a different slicer is selected.
Please Help.

Comment: what do you mean by different slicer is selected. I believe your slicer is on Dept i.e DEPT A DEPT B and so on. You show Effeciency based on dept right?

Comment: I've provided an answer with a rough model of what you need but if you provide a bit more detail, sample data, existing measure names then I can make the result more specific.

Comment: The measure would be something like `Close Rate = DIVIDE( CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( Events ), Events[EventStatus] = "Close" ), COUNTROWS( Events ) )`. But it is not clear to me what you mean by "avoid all slicers except one".

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a combination of CALCULATE and ALLEXCEPT. THe resulting measure will look something like this:

```
NewMeasure := CALCULATE([OriginalMeasure], ALLEXCEPT('MyTable'[Field To Keep Filters ON]))
```